# How is it possible that a project compiles in eclipse, but javac throws compiler errors?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

Working on a group project for school, and the following line throws an error when I run javac in the command line.

```
Object result = engine.eval(equation); //evaluate the arithmetic expression
cellValue = (double) result; // <-- This throws a compiler error (obviously)
```

But for some reason, this compiles and works(!) in eclipse, which my groupmates are using. I tried it for myself to confirm because I couldn't believe it.

```
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
```

engine is a ScriptEngine, if that's relevant at all. I can't for the life of me figure out how eclipse's compiler is allowing a line to be compiled that casts an `Object` directly to a `double`.

Comment: Is cellValue a double or a Double? If it is then the line should compile.

Comment: why do you think the compiler error was "obvious"?

Comment: because it's trying to cast an Object to a primitive...

Comment: javac -version: 1.6.0_24

Comment: @mavix That could be an allowed cast or not, depending on the type of cellValue.

Comment: With java 1.6 I am seeing: `Test.java:4: inconvertible types found   : java.lang.Object required: double`.  See if your friends are on 1.7.

Comment: FWIW:  Success in Java 7: http://ideone.com/eI6gQu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably your friends are using another version of the Java language. The cast of `Object` to `double` (the primitive type) seems to be legal in Java 7, but not in Java 6. You can have  your friends change their project settings in Eclipse or update your compiler to the version 7.

Note that casting `Object` to `Double` (the class) works in both versions.

Comment: I had both versions of Java installed in my machine, and uninstalling Java JDK 6 allowed it to compile.

Answer (score 5):

It appears the permitted conversions have been extended between Java 5 and 7. In the [Java Language Specification, 3rd edition (for Java 5 and 6)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.5):

> A value of a reference type can be cast to a primitive type by unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
>
> Unboxing conversion converts values of reference type to corresponding values of primitive type. Specifically, the following 8 conversion are called the unboxing conversions:
>
> - From type Boolean to type boolean
> - From type Byte to type byte
> - From type Character to type char
> - From type Short to type short
> - From type Integer to type int
> - From type Long to type long
> - From type Float to type float
> - From type Double to type double

So in Java 5 and 6, casting `Object` to `double` is not legal.

The [Java Language Specification, Java SE 7 Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5) writes:

> The following tables enumerate which conversions are used in certain casting conversions. Each conversion is signified by a symbol:
>
> ⇓ signifies narrowing reference conversion (§5.1.6)
>
> ⊔ signifies unboxing conversion (§5.1.8)

and the following table says a cast from Object to double to be

> ⇓,⊔

i.e. a cast from `Object` to `double` is a cast to `Double` followed by an unboxing conversion to `double`.

It is therefore very likely that your team mates are compiling for Java 7, while you are compiling for Java 6.

Answer (score 2):

Allowed casting conversions are detailed in the [JLS #5.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5). In particular, this conversion is allowed:

> - a narrowing reference conversion (§5.1.6) optionally followed by either an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) or an unchecked conversion (§5.1.9)

In your case, if `cellValue` is a double, the cast from `Object` is allowed and will try to cast `Object` to `Double` then to unbox the `Double` to `double`.

Comment: The same sentence also exists in the Java Language Specification for Java 5 and 6. I think it means that `double d = (Double) object` is permitted, not `double d = (double) object`.

Comment: I see what you mean. I think it allows `double d = (double) object;` based on the table 5.1 that follows, where a cast from Object to double is explicitly allowed (as well as Object to Double obviously).

Comment: Ah, you're right. I misread the old spec, where there is a sentence with nearly (but not quite) identical wording to the new one. Have an upvote :-)